# Как разбить большой .sql-файл на несколько маленьких?

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть .sql-файл (68 GB, 1 таблица). Нужно как-то его расчленить на несколько файлов, чтобы запихать в БД.

1. Ничто его не открывает.
2. SQLDumpSplitter его не делит.

Как быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Вариант1:**
`mysql -h localhost -u user -p mydatabase < cat mybigfile.sql` ?

**Вариант2:**
заходим в консоль `mysql` (`mysql -u user -p`)

```
USE yourdatabase;
SOURCE /path/to/the/sql/dump/mybigfile.sql;
```

Дополнение к варианту2 со StackOverflow:

```
mysql -u root -p
set global net_buffer_length=1000000; --Set network buffer length to a large byte number
set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000; --Set maximum allowed packet size to a large byte number
SET foreign_key_checks = 0; --Disable foreign key checking to avoid delays,errors and unwanted behaviour
source file.sql --Import your sql dump file
SET foreign_key_checks = 1; --Remember to enable foreign key checks when procedure is complete!
```

**ps;** если бы написали с какими ошибками вылетает было бы намного проще предложить workaround :)

Comment: В первом варианте можно без `cat`, просто `< /path/to/textfile`

Comment: ну да, можно так.

Comment: Решение с вариантом 2 будет в консоль сыпать ошибку - элементарно не выбрана БД. Если вы копируете решение рабочее и проверенное, то полностью )
А пропустили вы использование БД `use DATABASE_NAME;` перед строчкой `source ...`