# Нужно залить бэкап размером 27 Gb

Tags: mysql, dump

У меня есть большой бэкап. Мне нужно его залить на сервер. Пробовал через Sypex Dumper, через ssh. Не получилось, оба варианта зависали и приходилось перезапускать. Может кто знает, как поделить дамп на более мелкие части?

Comment: Только консоль. Ждать нужно будет довольно долго.

Comment: [Было уже](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/326986)

Comment: Use archiver, Luke!

Answer (score 0):

При помощи Filezilla по ssh с докачкой. Залейте файл на сервер, и уже на сервере делайте импорт.

Comment: Боюсь, что тут имеется в виду не закачка файла на сервер, а импорт бэкапа в саму базу данных.